# Git submodule in multiple folders

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a folder structure like this which I cannot change:

```
- root
-- craft
--- plugins
---- myplugin
--- templates
---- myplugin
```

At this moment everything is in a single repository. What I'd like to do is to create a submodule named "myPluginSubmodule" which contains both `myplugin` folders (from the `plugin` folder as well as the `templates` folder. Is this possible? If so, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. If this is your own architecture I would suggest rethinking the concept, e.g. like

```
- root
-- craft
--- plugins
---- myplugin
----- src
----- templates
```

If it isn't your architecture my guess is there should be a mechanism to install and maintain plugins already in place.

Either way: using Git submodules for dependency/plugin management is not a good basis. Package managers exist for almost all common languages, and they exist for a reason: they can resolve nested dependencies or warn against conflicts, something Git inherently can't do.

Comment: Could you please explain to me how I would setup composer for this module?

Comment: Is this a plugin for a framework that uses composer *and* this weird directory structure?

Comment: It's craft cms 2, it's without composer as far as I know

Comment: Judging from [the docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/templates) craft looks for plugin templates in `plugins/myplugin/templates`.

Comment: Not when using a frontend template unfortunately